# Cannot bind X UNIX socket within Docker container

Tags: docker, unix-socket, xvfb, xserver

I am trying to run Xvfb within a Docker container, but it is failing with the error:

```
$ Xvfb :0 -nolisten tcp -screen 0 1024x768x24
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

According to strace, it's trying to bind a UNIX socket at `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`:

```
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 20) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

However, the file does not already exist in the container (verified by `ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix`).

If I use a different screen number, like `:1`, the program succeeds.

This container is running in `--network host` mode, and `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` *does* exist on the host. Does this create some kind of issue where the container and the host cannot have a UNIX socket at the same path, even if that socket is not visible in the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an exciting error! You're running into a naming collision in the [UNIX domain socket abstract namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html#:%7E:text=abstract%3A%20an%20abstract%20socket%20address%20is%20distinguished). UNIX domain sockets in Linux can be created in two kinds of places: One, in the normal VFS, which can be inspected with `ls`; the other is the "abstract namespace", where socket names start with `'\0'` (yea, a literal null byte) and get cleaned up when the program creating the socket exits.

Now, your strace call shows that it attempts to listen on a socket name in the abstract namespace by showing the `sun_path` field's value starting with an `@`. This is not exactly clear, but that's how it goes...

Here's how it shows a "normal", VFS-backed socket:

```
:;    strace -e bind socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/asf-testing-hi STDOUT
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/tmp/asf-testing-hi"}, 21) = 0
```

And here's a socket in the abstract namespace:

```
:;    strace -e bind socat ABSTRACT-LISTEN:/tmp/asf-testing-hi STDOUT
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/asf-testing-hi"}, 22) = 0
```

Welp, there's that `@` sign.

Back to the original problem, it looks like [abstract unix domain socket namespaces are scoped to a network namespace](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/SocketAbstractNamespace?showcomments), which means that using "host" mode is guaranteed to result in collisions. What you probably have to do is set up a separate network namespace for that container, and create a bridge for every network interface on the host that you want the container to have available. I believe https://stackunderflow.dev/p/network-namespaces-and-docker/ might have a decent tutorial for doing this manually. Hope this helps!